# How to use MATCH Keyword for multi columns in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I created a table using `fts3`. I used following query to get a result

```
      String query = "SELECT "+ID+" as _id," + 
        NAME +  
        " from " + TABLENAME +
        " where " +  NAME + " MATCH '" + inputKeyword + "';";
        Log.w(TAG, query);
```

Which gives the list of Names based on the `inputKeyword`.

But it doesn't work for multi columns,

```
    String query = "SELECT "+ID+" as _id," + 
        NAME +  
        " from " + TABLENAME +
        " where " +  NAME + " MATCH '" + inputKeyword + "' AND "+ EMAILADDRESS + " MATCH '"+emailaddress+"';";
```

Which doesn't give any results and also saying you can't use `MATCH` in this query. 
How to do that?

Comment: `EMAILADDRESS + '"+emailaddress+"';";` is this bit correct? I am seeing double `;` and `'"+emailaddress+"';`

Comment: Take a look at this (maybe duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057254/how-do-you-match-multiple-column-in-a-table-with-sqlite-fts3/14593298#14593298

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you match multiple column in a table with SQLite FTS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057254/how-do-you-match-multiple-column-in-a-table-with-sqlite-fts3)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks like this:

```
SELECT ID as _id, Name
FROM TableName
WHERE Name MATCH 'xxx' AND EmailAddress'yyy'
```

This lacks the MATCH operator for the second column.
What you want should look like this:

```
SELECT ID as _id, Name
FROM TableName
WHERE TableName MATCH 'Name:xxx EmailAddress:yyy'
```

Comment: This will not work. FTS only allows one 'MATCH' per select statement and will throw an error for the syntax you described. The question staaar linked to has a working solution; use that instead.

Comment: Corrected. (And the linked question asks for matches in *any* column, not *all*.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently sqlite doesn't support combining OR queries with MATCH conditions. union works

```
SELECT  *
FROM    email_fts 
WHERE   "to" MATCH 'a@b.com'

UNION

SELECT  *
FROM    email_fts 
WHERE   "from" MATCH 'c@d.com'
```