# Full text search on subset of fields in SQLite 3.7.4

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, multiple-columns

**Context**

I have a table specified as

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE EmailAttachmentSearch USING 
fts4(entityId Varchar(255), name, subject, type, group, from, json);
```

**Requirement**

I need to allow users to search over `name`, `subject`, `type`, `group` and `from`.

**Conditions**

I am aware of the `notindexed` option but due to multiplatform compatibility we are limited to SQLite 3.7.4 on which `notindexed` is not supported.

**Problem**

I am trying to construct a query that will be en equivalent to `MATCH 'word1* word2*'` but will exclude `entityId` and `json` fields.

My attempts always result in either no data or too much data.

**Invalid example**

```
SELECT json
FROM EmailAttachmentSearch
WHERE EmailAttachmentSearch MATCH 
     '(name:word1* 
    OR type:word1* 
    OR subject:word1* 
    OR from:word1*)
AND   (name:word2* 
    OR type:word2* 
    OR subject:word2* 
    OR from:word2*)'
```

Comment: FTS does not have suffix searches; you cannot put `*` at the beginning of a search term.

Comment: ```MATCH '"*word1* *word2*"'``` seems to work?

Comment: Does it find `xxxword1`?

Comment: actually you are right

Comment: any idea how to do the thing I'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SQLite query engine doesn't support such complex conditions in the `MATCH` section. I've done more research and found that it is working pretty well when you use subqueries.

```
 SELECT json FROM EmailAttachmentSearch WHERE ROWID IN (
     SELECT ROWID FROM EmailAttachmentSearch WHERE EmailAttachmentSearch MATCH 'name:word1* OR type:word1* OR subject:word1* OR from:word1*'
     AND ROWID IN (
         SELECT ROWID FROM EmailAttachmentSearch WHERE EmailAttachmentSearch MATCH 'name:word2* OR type:word2* OR subject:word2* OR from:word2*'
     )
 );
```

Original answer here:

[How do you match multiple column in a table with SQLite FTS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057254/how-do-you-match-multiple-column-in-a-table-with-sqlite-fts3)