# How do you match multiple text in multiple column in a table with SQLite FTS3?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

I'm searching for Multiple text in multiple column of Virtual Table. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593298/2624806) thread, this search for a single word in multiple column.

I checked with following

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH (('A:cat OR C:cat') AND ('A:dog OR C:dog')
```

but it seems AND condition not working.

**EDIT** I have tried with following,

```
Select count (*) FROM Table1 WHERE TBL_VIRTUAL MATCH (('A:D* AND B:D* AND C:D*') OR ('A:tar* AND B:tar* AND C:tar*'));
Select count (*) FROM Table1 WHERE TBL_VIRTUAL MATCH (('A:D* AND B:D* AND C:D*') AND ('A:tar* AND B:tar* AND C:tar*'));
```

These both query return me same **109** result. Then I tried what @redneb mention in below answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH '(A:D* OR B:D* OR C: D*) AND (A:tar* OR B:tar* OR C:tar*)'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH '(A:D* OR B:D* OR C: D*) OR (A:tar* OR B:tar* OR C:tar*)'
```

But this return **0** result.

Any suggestion what I'm missing here!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable MATCH '(A:cat OR C:cat) AND (A:dog OR C:dog)';
```

However, I suspect that the following query will perform faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable MATCH '(A:cat AND C:dog) OR (A:dog AND C:cat)';
```

and is equivalent to the first one.

**Edit**: Here's a complete example. Let's create and populate a table first:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mytable USING fts3(A, C);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('foo','bar'),
    ('dog','dog'),
    ('cat','cat'),
    ('dog','cat'),
    ('cat','dog');
```

Then the query works as expected:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytable MATCH '(A:cat AND C:dog) OR (A:dog AND C:cat)';
A           C         
----------  ----------
dog         cat       
cat         dog
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question with condition you suggest. But it's not producing expected result. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

For **OR** condition type OR between                   i.e. : `MATCH ('A:cat OR C:cat')`

For **AND** condition just **don't** type **anything** i.e. : `MATCH ('A:cat C:cat')`